# Should students' presentations be listed on your CV if you're a co-author?

Tags: cv, presentation

In my experience, it is quite common for graduate students and professors to be listed as a co-author of undergraduate students' presentations. Although you may be listed as a co-author, should these presentations have a place in your CV?

I've seen undergraduate students' presentations written differently in various CV's. In some CV's, they have a separate section titled "Presentations by students", whereas in others, the presentations are just listed under the same "Presentations" heading as theirs.

Is there a convention for how to list students' presentations (posters and oral/slide) on one's CV when you're listed as a co-author? Is this different depending on whether you are a graduate student with undergraduate students, or a professor with both undergraduate and graduate students?

Also, would this convention also change depending on whether the presentation by the student is given at local, less reputable symposiums (e.g., undergraduate research symposiums) versus large scale conferences (e.g., APA Annual Conference)?

Comment: Could you clarify what it means to be an author of a presentation?

Comment: Note that there may be some field-to-field variability on this issue. In some fields (e.g. biomedical) journal publications are the primary communication vehicle, and presentations are mostly just re-tellings of one or more journal articles. (Thus little to no credit on being a "coauthor" of a presentation.) In other fields (e.g. computer science), conferences and conference proceedings are the primary communication method, and hence being a coauthor of a conference presentation is a big deal. -- You may want to edit your question to make your particular field clear.